# Rails 3 views refactoring: conditionals and finds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, find, conditional-statements

What would you recommend as the best way to refactor these two bits of view code?

```
<%if Supplydetail.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).first.nil? %>
<%else%>
<%if Productavailability.find_by_code(Supplydetail.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).first.productsupply_supplydetail_productavailability).nil? %>
<%else%>
<li><%= Productavailability.find_by_code(Supplydetail.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).first.productsupply_supplydetail_productavailability).value %></li>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

and (using formtastic)

```
%li.tip 
  = tooltip(:test, :hover)
= f.input :relatedmaterial_relatedproduct_idvalue, :label => "Related ISBN", :as => :select, :collection => Isbn.all, :label_method => :descriptivedetail_titledetail_titleelement_titlewithoutprefix, :value_method => :productidentifier_idvalue  
%li.list
  = link_to "Edit list", isbns_path
```

I have examples of each of these about a bazillion times in my app, and would like to know I'm refactoring in the best way before I dive in to this rather huge job.

Comment: for  the first part of code. Please cut this from view immediately and paste to the controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, an empty `if` branch in an if/else usually (but not always!) smells bad so don't do that, it just makes your code harder to read and understand.

Also, you're computing `Supplydetail.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn)` and `Productavailability.find_by_code(...)` twice just to get your `<li>` output. Don't do that either.

And you might want to push most of that logic into your controller (or maybe a helper depending on where and how often it is used) to cut down on the ERB-noise.

Maybe something like this would serve you (and whoever gets to maintain your code) better; a bit of controller stuff first:

```
@avail  = nil
by_isbn = Supplydetail.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).first
if by_isbn
    @avail = Productavailability.find_by_code(by_isbn.productsupply_supplydetail_productavailability)
end
```

And then in your ERB:

```
<% if @avail %>
    <li><%= @avail.value %></li> 
<% end %>
```

If you're doing a lot of this sort of thing then you could add a `Productavailability.for_isbn` convenience class method in your model. Then your controller would just need:

```
@avail = Productavailability.for_isbn(@isbn)
```

But I wouldn't worry about it until you start repeating yourself.

I'm not familiar with formtastic so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Brilliant, ta. It's interesting that you recommend putting code in the controller - I was worried about solving one problem (a jam-packed view) by creating another (a fat controller). Let the refactoring commence!

Comment: @snowangel: A couple extra lines in a controller isn't exactly "fat", especially when it is just doing its job by setting up some data for the view. If you're doing a lot of that then you could push most of it down into a convenience method in your model as in my update to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I've got lots - your advice is invaluable, thank you. As well as the better-maintainability reason, does pushing stuff into the controller and model improve performance?

Comment: @snowangel: There might be a slight speed boost from moving things out of ERB but probably nothing you'd notice unless you've been very naughty and loaded your templates with a lot of code. I think you'd notice the "don't hit the database twice for the same thing" first.

Comment: [twists hanky in case I've been naughty without knowing it] erm, when you say 'templates', do you mean the erb files?

Comment: @snowangel: Yes, as in "ERB template". Cleaning up the mistakes you've made is now you learn your lessons :)